# jQuery Mobile data-role="header" click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a refresh button in the header of my jQuery mobile app and the click event will not fire in my browser (Chrome).  Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a id="#refresh_deals" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true" data-icon="refresh"></a>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-title" data-inline="true"><input id="main_search" data-mini="true" type="search" /></div>
    <a id="map_btn" data-inline="true" data-mini="true" data-transition="slide" href="#gps_map">Map</a>
</div><!-- header -->
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $('#refresh_deals').on('click', function(){
        console.log('refresh clicked')
    });
});
```

It's a pretty simple thing but have no luck with it! I have tried the tap event and pretty much everything else I could find around the web.  Does anyone have any idea as to what is going on here?

Comment: The `#` in your selector tells jQuery that it's looking for an ID, but your id is `#refresh_deals`, so your selector would need to be `##refresh_deals`. Or more likely your ID was supposed to be just `refresh_deals`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect, try changing this:

```
<a id="#refresh_deals" ... />
```

to this:

```
<a id="refresh_deals" ... />
```